# Will HotSpot JVM change young generation size dynamically?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Some question about HotSpot JVM Garbage Collection.

We have a java process running and the opts are:

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-Xloggc:/mnt/dfs/0/hdfs/logs/namenode.gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=1 -XX:GCLogFileSize=512M -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:-DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection 
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -server -Xmx92160m -Xms92160m 
-Xss256k -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

as you see, the max heap size is about 90G.

According to [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html), NewRatio=2 and SurvivorRatio=8 in default. So the Eden
 size should be 90G*1/3*8/10=24G, and survivor size should be 90G*1/3*1/10=3G.

But in fact, when I use jstat:

```
sudo jstat -gcnew 37082
S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U   TT MTT  DSS      EC       EU     YGC     YGCT  
48960.0 48960.0    0.0 5981.3 15  15 24480.0 391936.0  82332.7  13351 1379.450
```

Eden size is only about 390MB, and survivor size only 48MB. This causes a lot of young gc.

Can anyone tell me the reason why Eden size is so small?

Comment: I know for a fact that all the generation sizes are being adapted dynamically by default. Since none of your options seem to change this, that's probably what you should have as well. I advise using VisualGC to monitor this (it's an optional plugin of VisualVM).

Answer (score 2):

Eden size is only as large as it needs to be. The NewSize will be larger if you generate more short lived garbage.

Answer (score 2):

From here this [this Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html)!

> I could understand that  When the heap grows or shrinks, the JVM must recalculate the old and new generation sizes to maintain a predefined NewRatio.,
>
> The NewSize and MaxNewSize parameters control the new generation’s minimum and maximum size.
>
> The size of the young generation relative to the old generation is controlled by NewRatio. For example, setting -XX:NewRatio=3 means that the ratio between the old and young generation is 1:3, the combined size of eden and the survivor spaces will be fourth of the heap.

To size the Java heap:

> Make plenty of memory available to the young generation. The default is calculated from NewRatio and the -Xmx setting.

Can you try setting  a value for NewSize  and see if that makes a difference?